# Find examples of formulas with the following characteristics.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

(a.) Find an example of a formula with at least one quantifier that is $\textbf{false}$
when we quantify over the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, but $\textbf{true}$
when we quantify over the integer numbers $\mathbb{Z}$.

$(\exists x \in \mathbb{N} : x < 0)\textbf{, False}$

$(\exists x \in \mathbb{Z} : x < 0)\textbf{, True}$

Do this work or is the first one undefined?

Comment: Rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ or integer numbers $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, this works, as long as all symbols are defined ($<$ and $0$).

Comment: @AirMike It was supposed to be integer numbers $\mathbb{Z}$, I edited that now

Comment: I have one doubt: why do you think the first one would be undefined?

Comment: @AirMike Because there is no negativ numbers in $\mathbb{N}$.